# MediaPlayer not looping a raw resource MP3 file (Kotlin)

Tags: loops, kotlin, listener, android-mediaplayer, raw

Can someone help me to loop my audio source?  I'm new to using the MediaPlayer, but I cannot get it to loop the sound.  The sound plays, then quits and never starts up again.

I have read countless articles, and tried adding listeners to detect errors and end of play, but they are not getting triggered.

Here is a sample of my Kotlin code

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // Code for activity_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Init
        var textView: TextView
        var txtSceneDesc: TextView
        var txtPlayerCmd: TextView
        var txtSceneText: String
        textView = findViewById(R.id.txtSceneDescription)
        textView.movementMethod = ScrollingMovementMethod()
        txtSceneDesc = findViewById(R.id.txtSceneDescription)
        txtPlayerCmd = findViewById(R.id.textInputEditText)

        var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = null  // for playing sounds
        //val id = this.resources.getIdentifier("ocean_waves.mp3", "raw", this.packageName)
        val id = getResources().getIdentifier(
            "ocean_waves",
            "raw", getPackageName()
        );
        var r_Sound_Water: Int = id


        // Completion listener
        mediaPlayer?.setOnCompletionListener {
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Playback Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            mediaPlayer?.reset()
            mediaPlayer?.start()
            // You can perform other actions here as needed.
        }

        // Error listener
        mediaPlayer?.setOnErrorListener { MediaPlayer, what, extra ->
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Playback Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            // Return true if the error was handled, false otherwise.
            true
        }

        if (mediaPlayer == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Media player is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this@MainActivity, r_Sound_Water)
            mediaPlayer.isLooping = true
            mediaPlayer.start()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Media Player is assigned", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            mediaPlayer.start()
        }

        textView.text = "Run 29"

        // End code for activity_main.xml
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `mediaPlayer.isLooping = true` is enough to accomplish your intent.

For simplicity, below code should work without problem:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ocean_waves)
    mediaPlayer.isLooping = true
    mediaPlayer.start()
}
```

Please examine it for yourself.

Your problem's root may be other place.

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for your response.  I have tried that code, but I get the same result.  The sound stops playing and does not loop.

Answer (score 0):

`MediaPlayer` is a state machine. Properties such as `isLooping` and `volume` should be changed when the player is in the `PREPARED` state.

Try this:

```
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener { mp -> mp.isLooping = true }
mediaPlayer.start()
```

Comment: Thanks all for the advice.  So you know, the cause was the mp3 file itself.  It plays in Windows media player just fine, but for some reason it will not loop in Android media player, but instead stops halfway through the file with no error detected in my listener.  The file is 3 minutes long.  I had converted it from a WAV to MP3 using a web converter site.  I still need to do more testing to see if the length of the file is the issue or something else.